# Which IC component is this?

Tags: motor-controller, hobbyist

I seem to have burned out this chip on my Hobby King [ESC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_speed_control) (see picture). I am not able to read the component part number. The ESC is no longer available to buy. What is the part number (so that I may fix it)?

It's this one, BTW. https://hobbyking.com/en_us/hobbyking-40a-2-6s-esc-w-ubec-4a.html?___store=en_us

[image: HobbyKing 40A (2~6S) ESC w/UBEC 4A]

[image: Burned chip]

Comment: What IC, the black chip roughly in the middle? That's an ATmega. ATMEGA8AU-TW354VAN174476J by the looks of it.

Comment: No the one next to the Inductor. Bottom Left. You can see burn damage on it. The only letters I can read is  AP15***

Comment: Note that the wire connections at the bottom of your board are also in poor condition.

Comment: I believe thats the reason the IC must have burned out. There was clearly a short curcuit in the +5V & GND cable which would draw 4A, the max the UBEC can deliver.

Comment: I would guess a switch regulator from some obscure vendor.

Comment: @Lundin Nope, not obscure at all. Diodes Incorporated.

Comment: @DerStrom8 Ah yeah, nice catch. I should actually know that, since I've used Diodes regulators in the past.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That logo looks like Diodes Incorporated:

[image]

If I had to guess, I would say that IC is probably an AP1539 from Diodes Incorporated, which is an adjustable buck regulator (consistent with the surrounding circuitry). I would suggest [AP1539SDPG-13 - IC REG BUCK ADJUSTABLE 4A 8SOP](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/products_inactive_data/AP1539.pdf). The pinout in the datasheet seems to match the connections that are visible in the image, as well as the package markings:

[image]